# Broadcastreceiver not listening even after app launches maually in ICS

Tags: android

My application displays music metadata if music is playing in the background. In ICS device, even after launching app manually, the broadcast receiver is not registered. It works fine for the versions below. I added a portion of my code below, do I want to add any intent action in the manifext file?

```
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
// Android Stock Music App / Google Play Music App
 iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
// HTC music player`enter code here`
iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
// WinAmp
iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
// Samsung Music App
iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String track =intent.getStringExtra("track");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided work, but it needs an activity(are you using activity). On Android 3.1+, an application is installed in a "stopped" state. While in that state, no BroadcastReceiver will work, until the user manually launches an activity from the application. The application will return to this "stopped" state if the user force-stops the application from Settings.

So, add an activity to your project, launch it once, and then see if your receiver works.
Otherwise try to register broadcast receiver in manifest file..

Hope explanation works for you.

Comment: The code is inside an activity only ,  i tried with registering in manifest , both not working.I'm able get metadata if any action is done on music player like next,prev,stop, but i want to get data while playing

Comment: Are you trying to create your own widget for showing song details

Comment: If you trying to do so then keep in mind,

Music widgets are designed to integrate with a certain player, and you can't make 
your own widget easily integrate with another media player.

Comment: So,i think you can make use of service to keep track of Media player instance..

If helps appreciate..

Comment: Not using any own music widget, show the meta data of currently playing music  in any player in UI

Comment: as i said above go for service

Comment: It's working fine for samsung ICS when I changed to manifest file, but not working for soniericcson eventhough i added filer <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged" />
    <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.music.playstatechanged" /> in manifest file.

Comment: when i printed the running process i got the following process related to music....Process com.sonyericsson.music with component com.sonyericsson.music.equalizer.EqualizerServiceImpl
Process com.sonyericsson.music with component com.sonyericsson.music.equalizer.EqualizerServiceImpl
Process com.sonyericsson.music with component com.sonyericsson.music.playbackservice.MediaPlaybackServiceImpl
Process com.sonyericsson.music with component com.sonyericsson.music.playbackservice.MediaPlaybackServiceImpl

Comment: see this manifest and if helpful refer this project [link](http://code.google.com/p/a-simple-lastfm-scrobbler/source/browse/trunk/a_simple_lastfm_scrobbler/AndroidManifest.xml?r=280)